# Ambiguous output redirect while trying to setup passwordless ssh

Tags: ssh, passwords

I have installed keychain using the command:

```
apt-get install keychain
```

then, I tried to set up a passwordless ssh connection like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

After that,

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

it attempts for password but the following error is displayed:

```
.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
Ambiguous output redirect
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try first logging onto the host again (with your password), and then running `ssh-keygen` (with no arguments) there. I think that should create a `.ssh` directory there for you.

And then (back on your local machine) when you run `ssh-copy-id`, it should work.